# Echo selected when using a drop down box

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change this code to a dropdown menu which i can do however i can't get it to echo the selected choice.

This is my current working code but with this i have to type in manually the word true or false then click udpate.

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h6 class="form-text text-info">Auto changing backgrounds enter true or false</h6>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="background image rotating" name="sett2" value="<?php echo $row3['sett2'];?>">
                        </div>
```

I have tried a few variants but struggling to get it to work, this is what i tried;

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h6 class="form-text text-info">Auto changing backgrounds enter true or false</h6>
                            <select class="select form-control" name="sett2" value="<?php echo $sett2;?>">
                                    <option value="true">True</option>
                                    <option value="false">False</option>
                        </div>
```

and also this;

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
                        
                        <?php
                         $settwo =  $_REQUEST['sett2'];
                         ?> 
                            <h6 class="form-text text-info">Auto change backgrounds</h6>
                            <select class="select form-control" id="select" name="sett2">
                                    <option value="true" <?php if($settwo == true){ echo 'selected';} ?>>True</option>
                                    <option value="false" <?php if($settwo == false){ echo 'selected';} ?>>False</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis on comparison

```
<?php
$settwo =  $_REQUEST['sett2'];
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?> 
<h6 class="form-text text-info">Auto change backgrounds</h6>
<form>
    <select class="select form-control" id="select" name="sett2">
        <option value="true" <?php if($settwo == 'true'){ echo 'selected';} ?>>True</option>
        <option value="false" <?php if($settwo == 'false'){ echo 'selected';} ?>>False</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Explanation: your php code tries to compare boolean true value to string 'true' and in this case it gets ir right. Following code will output to true:

```
var_dump(true == 'true');
```

Hower false is not equal to 'false'.

```
var_dump(false == 'false');
```

Will output false.

Answer (score 0):

your code apostrophe forgotten `'true'`

```
<?php if($settwo == 'true'){ echo 'selected';} ?>
<?php if($settwo == 'false'){ echo 'selected';} ?>
```